# How to calculate distinct & continuous range

Tags: sql-server

This is the table structure which records each query on a cache.

```
SequenceId CacheInstance QueryCondition
------------------------------------------
1          100              'x=1 '
2          100              'x=1'
3          100              'y=a'
4          100              'x=1'
5          200              'x=1'
5          200              'x=1'
```

Is there a simple statement to get the folloing "distinct count"?

```
CacheInstance QueryCondition distinctcount
-------------------------------------------
100            'x=1'             2
100            'y=a'             1
200            'x=1'             1
```

If'x=1' occurs continuously, it is counted as same one. But if it occurs after a different query condition, the distinct count will increase 1.

Answer (score 2):

try this...using group by

```
  select CacheInstance,QueryCondition ,COUNT(QueryCondition) as distinctcount from YourtableName group by CacheInstance,QueryCondition
```

Answer (score 0):

Use group by for those two columns

```
CREATE TABLE Cache
(
    SequenceId int,
    CacheInstance int,
    QueryCondition nvarchar(20)
)

SELECT CacheInstance, QueryCondition, COUNT(QueryCondition)
FROM Cache
GROUP BY CacheInstance, QueryCondition
```